# Order of classloading in JBoss 6.4: Is WEB-INF/classes or modules loaded first?

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, jboss6.x, jboss-modules

I have a property file named `abc.properties` in my `WAR`'s `WEB-INF/classes`. Also, I have placed it inside a (correctly registered) module. When I then call:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("abc")
```

which file would be picked?

In our production environment, the file placed inside the `WAR` is being picked (*consistently*) but in the UAT environment (with the same version of JBoss), its the property file in the module that is getting picked (*consistently*)

Is there a defined order in which resources are loaded into classpath by JBoss, or does this happen randomly? (We haven't *observed* any randomness though.)

(The module is correctly registered in the production server, as other resources, namely the `ojdbc jar` placed in the module are getting loaded correctly)

This is our module.xml in the registered module

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="properties"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

`abc.properties` is placed inside the `properties` folder as defined in the above module

**P.S:** I understand that its a wrong practice to have two property files of the same name placed in such a manner, but I want to know why am I seeing such a behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the official [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/development_guide/chap-class_loading_and_modules#Class_Loading_Precedence) regarding the classloading precedence for EAP 6.4